# Facebook Android SDK: get mutual friends

Tags: android, facebook, request

I am trying to get the mutual friends of two Facebook users, using the Android SDK:

```
Request friendsInCommon = Request.newRestRequest(myFbSession, "me/mutualfriends/otherUserId", null, HttpMethod.GET);
```

This, however, returns the following error:

```
03-16 04:24:39.652: D/ViewProfile(27121): My friends list: {Response:  responseCode: 200, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: 200, errorCode: 3, errorType: null, errorMessage: Unknown method}, isFromCache:false}
```

Any clues on what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone is interested, I finally solved this by treating the request as a Graph API request:

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("fields", "id,name,picture");
Request req = new Request(myFbSession, "me/mutualfriends/otherUserId", params, HttpMethod.GET, new Callback(){
    @Override
    public void onCompleted(Response response) {
        // your callback code
    }
});
req.executeAsync();
```

Answer (score 1):

I know its too late to answer this question but **me/mutualfriends/otherUserId** is deprecated in Facebook Graph API v2.0 and above, so this is the right way to get mutual friends in Graph API v2.0 and above

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
            params.putString("fields", "context.fields(mutual_friends)");
            new GraphRequest(
                    AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                    "/" + fbId,
                    params,
                    HttpMethod.GET,
                    new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse graphResponse) {
                            try {
                                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(graphResponse.getRawResponse());
                                if (jsonObject.has("context")) {
                                   jsonObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("context");
                                if (jsonObject.has("mutual_friends")) {
                                    JSONArray mutualFriendsJSONArray = jsonObject.getJSONObject("mutual_friends").getJSONArray("data");
                                  // this mutualFriendsJSONArray contains the id and name of the mutual friends.
                                }
                              }
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
            ).executeAsync();
```

For official documentation refer this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/user.context/mutual_friends